# ngFor stop automatic newline

Tags: angular, ngfor

Is there anyway to stop an ngFor loop putting each element on a new line?

This is the code I have now

```
<div class="groups">
    <h3>Groups:</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" class="group">
       <button (click)="changeGroup(i)">{{group}}{{i}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces this

[image]

How can I make the buttons appear in the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using bootstrap this is the way to put it in a line.

```
<div class="groups row">
    <h3>Groups:</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" class="group">
     <div class="col-1">  
        <button (click)="changeGroup(i)">{{group}}{{i}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

or using simple CSS

```
<div class="groups">
    <h3>Groups:</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" class="group">
     <div style="display:inline-block;">  
        <button (click)="changeGroup(i)">{{group}}{{i}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS is not needed, just change the div with the ngfor to a span tag.

Answer (score 4):

The `ngFor` loop is on the `div` elements. Since these are block elements, you end up with a vertical stack of `div` containers, each one containing a button.

To get one block with all the buttons inside, put the `ngFor` loop on the `button` element:

```
<div class="groups">
    <h3>Groups:</h3>
    <div class="group">
       <button *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" (click)="changeGroup(i)">{{group}}{{i}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, but just change the inner div to span tag so the the class group is aplied to each item.

Answer (score 2):

> The Angular ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't
>   interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
>   DOM

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" class="group">
   <button (click)="changeGroup(i)">{{group}}{{i}}</button>
</ng-container>
```